Which scriptures identify the births Vishnu's doorkeepers took to fulfill the Kumaras' curse?
from
https://iskcondesiretree.com/profiles/blogs/story-of-three-births-of-jay-and-vijay-who-were-gatekeepers-of

At the end of the Dwapara Yuga - Jaya and Vijaya were born their third birth as Shishupala and Dantavakra (an ally of Jarasandha, a friend of Shishupala and an enemy of Vasudeva Krishna) and Lord Krishna appreared Himself along with Balarama and killed them. Therefore, two attendants of the Lord in Vaikuntha named Jaya and Vijaya became Hirakyakasipu and Hiranyakka in Satya-yuga, Ravana and Kumbhakarna in the Treta-yuga, and as Shishupala and Dantavakra at the end of Dvapara-yuga. Because of their fruitive acts, Jaya and Vijaya agreed to become the Lord's enemies, and when killed in that mentality, they attained salvation in oneness.

Is this just folklore or do scriptures mention this?

This incident is described in Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 7.1.

श्रीनारद उवाच
एकदा ब्रह्मण: पुत्रा विष्णुलोकं यद‍ृच्छया ।
सनन्दनादयो जग्मुश्चरन्तो भुवनत्रयम् ॥ ३६ ॥

The great saint Nārada said: Once upon a time when the four sons of
Lord Brahmā named Sanaka, Sanandana, Sanātana and Sanat-kumāra were
wandering throughout the three worlds, they came by chance to
Viṣṇuloka.
पञ्चषड्ढायनार्भाभा: पूर्वेषामपि पूर्वजा: । दिग्वासस: शिशून् मत्वा
द्वा:स्थौ तान् प्रत्यषेधताम् ॥ ३७ ॥

Although these four great sages were older than Brahmā’s other sons
like Marīci, they appeared like small naked children only five or six
years old. When Jaya and Vijaya saw them trying to enter
Vaikuṇṭhaloka, these two gatekeepers, thinking them ordinary children,
forbade them to enter.
अशपन् कुपिता एवं युवां वासं न चार्हथ: । रजस्तमोभ्यां रहिते पादमूले
मधुद्विष: । पापिष्ठामासुरीं योनिं बालिशौ यातमाश्वत: ॥ ३८ ॥

Thus checked by the doorkeepers Jaya and Vijaya, Sanandana and the
other great sages very angrily cursed them. “You two foolish
doorkeepers,” they said. “Being agitated by the material qualities of
passion and ignorance, you are unfit to live at the shelter of
Madhudviṣa’s lotus feet, which are free from such modes. It would be
better for you to go immediately to the material world and take your
birth in a family of most sinful asuras.”
एवं शप्तौ स्वभवनात् पतन्तौ तौ कृपालुभि: । प्रोक्तौ पुनर्जन्मभिर्वां
त्रिभिर्लोकाय कल्पताम् ॥ ३९ ॥

While Jaya and Vijaya, thus cursed by the sages, were falling to the
material world, they were addressed as follows by the same sages, who
were very kind to them. “O doorkeepers, after three births you will be
able to return to your positions in Vaikuṇṭha, for then the duration
of the curse will have ended.”
जज्ञाते तौ दिते: पुत्रौ दैत्यदानववन्दितौ । हिरण्यकशिपुर्ज्येष्ठो
हिरण्याक्षोऽनुजस्तत: ॥ ४० ॥

These two associates of the Lord — Jaya and Vijaya — later descended
to the material world, taking birth as the two sons of Diti,
Hiraṇyakaśipu being the elder and Hiraṇyākṣa the younger. They were
very much respected by the Daityas and Dānavas [demoniac species].
ततस्तौ राक्षसौ जातौ केशिन्यां विश्रव:सुतौ । रावण: कुम्भकर्णश्च
सर्वलोकोपतापनौ ॥ ४४ ॥

Thereafter the same Jaya and Vijaya, the two doorkeepers of Lord
Viṣṇu, took birth as Rāvaṇa and Kumbhakarṇa, begotten by Viśravā in
the womb of Keśinī. They were extremely troublesome to all the people
of the universe.
तावत्र क्षत्रियौ जातौ मातृष्वस्रात्मजौ तव । अधुना शापनिर्मुक्तौ
कृष्णचक्रहतांहसौ ॥ ४६ ॥

In their third birth, the same Jaya and Vijaya appeared in a family of
kṣatriyas as your cousins, the sons of your aunt. Because Lord Kṛṣṇa
has struck them with His disc, all their sinful reactions have been
destroyed, and now they are free from the curse.
Purport by Swami Prabhupada: In their last birth, Jaya and Vijaya did not become demons or
Rākṣasas. Instead they took birth in a very exalted kṣatriya family
related to Kṛṣṇa’s family. They became first cousins of Lord Kṛṣṇa and
were practically on an equal footing with Him. By personally killing
them with His own disc, Lord Kṛṣṇa destroyed whatever sinful reactions
were left in them because of the curse of the brāhmaṇas. Nārada Muni
explained to Mahārāja Yudhiṣṭhira that by entering Kṛṣṇa’s body,
Śiśupāla reentered Vaikuṇṭhaloka as the Lord’s associate. Everyone had
seen this incident.
वैरानुबन्धतीव्रेण ध्यानेनाच्युतसात्मताम् । नीतौ पुनर्हरे: पार्श्वं
जग्मतुर्विष्णुपार्षदौ ॥ ४७ ॥

These two associates of Lord Viṣṇu — Jaya and Vijaya — maintained a
feeling of enmity for a very long time. Because of always thinking of
Kṛṣṇa in this way, they regained the shelter of the Lord, having
returned home, back to Godhead.
Purport by Swami Prabhupada: Whatever their position, certainly Jaya and Vijaya always thought of
Kṛṣṇa. Therefore at the end of the mauṣala-līlā, these two associates
of the Lord returned to Kṛṣṇa. There is no difference between Kṛṣṇa’s
body and Nārāyaṇa’s body. Therefore although they visibly entered the
body of Kṛṣṇa, they actually reentered Vaikuṇṭhaloka as the
doorkeepers of Lord Viṣṇu. Through Lord Kṛṣṇa’s body, they returned to
Vaikuṇṭha, although they seemed to have attained sāyujya-mukti in
Kṛṣṇa’s body.

